# UWP Raise ObservableCollection CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Windows 10 UWP C#

I have a class for ListView grouping from MSDN example:

```
public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have grouped collection which is binded to `CollectionViewSource` and `ListView`:

```
ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> TransactionsCollection 
                                    = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();
```

When I add or remove some items from collection nothing happens. The `CollectionChanged` Event not raising.

Delete example:

```
foreach (var x in TransactionsCollection)
        {
            if (x.Key.ToString() == item.displayGroupName)
            {
                x.Remove(x.Find(i => ((Transaction)i).Id == item.Id));
                return;
            }
        }
```

How I can call `CollectionChanged` Event?

Comment: You're not removing anything from your `ObservableCollection`, you're removing things from the `GroupInfoList`'s in that observable collection.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, Yes you are right. But how I can to call `ObservableCollection` Changed Event when I delete items from `GroupInfoList` or add new items there?

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for GroupInfoList class. You will get notified when item is changed or make GroupInfoList  as ObservableCollection

Comment: You don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` here (unless you want to be notified when that `Key` property is changed), you need `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Letting `GroupInfoList` inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` is one way to do that. Personally I'd question the inheriting-from-a-collection approach (and the use of `object` instead of making `GroupInfoList` generic), as opposed to using composition, but oh well.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thx. Its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
public class GroupInfoList : ObservableCollection<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```